# How to delete geometry that is inside the base mesh using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have created instances of curves on the surface of a mesh, and then distorted them using a noise texture. Since the distortion is quite aggressive (and I want it that way) it has ended up with some of the geometry clipping inside the base mesh. This is undesirable and I would like to delete the geometry inside the mesh, but I can't figure out how. Raycast only deletes some of the geometry and does it both inside and outside of the mesh

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean works, though costly and unreliable :

edit : kinda works, it generates points at the intersection between the 2 meshes.

1. Generate points outside and inside target geometry : [image]
2. Boolean set to Difference, Hole Tolerant : [image]